# Cloning a Websphere Portal 8.5 from AIX to Linux

Tags: linux, unix, websphere, websphere-portal, cloning

We have a WebSphere Portal Cluster V8.5 on AIX PowerPC OS. i want to move it to one of the Linux Based OS such as (RedHat, CentOS, Oracle etc..). Is it possible? how is it done? is it enough to copy the installation folder from AIX to Linux /usr/IBM/WebSphere/ or do i need to make a new installation on Linux and migrate the profiles? I'll appreciate the Help on this issue.
I have cloned a WebSphere Portal from one AIX OS to another AIX before, and i changed the hostname and nodename accordingly and it works perfectly. but never cloned a websphere portal from one OS (Unix) to another (Linux). and before trying it would like to know if someone has done it or tested it before.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Joe

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: Not really, it is more of understanding if ibm websphere portal version 8.5 installed on a unix OS will work as well on linux OS when copying/moving the filesystem / installation folder from a unix server to a linux server.

Comment: @JosephSayegh Then why are you asking it here? There's ServerFault designated for questions like these. Despite the fact that there's a bunch of IBM employees here on SO who die to answer off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

it is best to do a new install and then do a staging to production copy of the system.  I have seen the copy work between machines that are the same os, but you may run into java problems at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Binaries are different. You need to install linux verison of Portal and then you may chose to do export and import. Even PAA would work in this case. We recently upgraded our portal version from 6.1 to 8.5 and also had moved out of AIX to Linux. We have followed the same strategy. If you fall into any issue, you may reach out.